# how to reduce the code duplication in my navigation menu

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I use a floating navigation menu for my project so I need it in every single page this is my code

```
  <customRenderes:NavigationImageButton Source="IconFAB"
                                          x:Name="NavigationImageButton"
                                          ItemTapped="NavigationImageButton_OnItemTapped"

                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.0,1.0,-1,-1"
                                Margin="10"
                                Opacity="0.4"
```

I need to overcome this code duplication so can anyone suggest a way to do this

Comment: create a BasePage that your other pages inherit from and put this code in the base

Comment: @jason How to to this what u are saying can you explain it in example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a template resource in a xaml resource dictionary which you import in App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary ... />
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="PageTemplate">
    <Grid>
      <!-- Any pages with content that use this template will display contents in this ContentPresenter -->
      <ContentPresenter />
      <!-- Add elements common to all pages, TemplateBinding looks at the code behind for properties on the page being displayed through this template -->
      <FloatingNavigationMenu Contents={TemplateBinding MenuContents} />
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, apply this template to your pages:

```
<ContentPage ControlTemplate={StaticResource PageTemplate}>
  ...
</ContentPage>
```

If you wanted to, you could create a base contentpage class, and in the constructor you could do:

```
public abstract class BasePage : ContentPage
{
  public BasePage()
  {      
    SetDynamicResource(ControlTemplateProperty, "PageTemplate");
  }
  ...
}
```

Doing this, pages inheriting from BasePage will automatically have the template applied. You would probably want to define your properties that are bound to your NavigationMenu in this base page class as well.

Comment: <FloatingNavigationMenu Contents={TemplateBinding MenuContents} /> what you mean by this FloatingNavigationMenu

Comment: That's just a type I made up, you could add your customRenderes:NavigationImageButton there instead, and bind it's BindableProperties to properties on the page's xaml.cs